# Notepad++ Remove One Word Surrounded by a Sentence

Tags: regex, notepad++

**sentence:** WOMACK ARMY HOSPITAL  null    2817    ~ Reilly ft Rd~ 28310

**expected:** WOMACK ARMY HOSPITAL  null    2817    ~ Reilly~   28310

*word groups are separated by tabs.*

I need to remove every word enclosed in between the tilde symbols (~) that contain 2 letters or less.

my current regex doesn't find it.

**find what:** ~[^ ]{1,2}~

**replace with:** nothing

This needs to work multi-line.

Comment: Your example doesn't fit your description. The example also removes the spaces before those words. Please clarify.

Comment: Try `~\h*\S+\K[^~]+(?=~)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works with one line but removes lines below?

Comment: Ah, ok, so if there is `HOSPITAL null 2817 ~ fs Reilly go Kara ~ 28310` you want to get `HOSPITAL null 2817 ~ Reilly Kara ~ 28310`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, correct but should work for every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|~)[^~\n]*?\K[^\n\w]*\b\w{1,2}\b(?=[^~\n]*~)
```

Replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/a6sMqO/2).

Note that I added `\n` to the negated character classes to make sure you only match within lines (without overflowing from one line to another).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|~)` - the end of the previous match or a tilde
- `[^~\n]*?`  - 0+ chars other than tilde and newline, as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `[^\n\w]*` - 0+ chars other than word and newline chars, as many as possible
- `\b\w{1,2}\b`  - 1 or 2 char words (replace `\w` with `\pL` to only match letters)
- `(?=[^~\n]*~)` - there must be a tilde after 0+ chars other than tilde and newline (to make sure we have a closing `~` on the same line).

Notepad++ settings:

[image]

Comment: works like a charm. what a complex regex. thank you.